# Managing multiple Twisted client connections

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to use Twisted in a sort of spidering program that manages multiple client connections.  I'd like to maintain of a pool of about 5 clients working at one time.  The functionality of each client is to connect to a specified IRC server that it gets from a list, enter a specific channel, and then save the list of the users in that channel to a database.

The problem I'm having is more architectural than anything.  I'm fairly new to Twisted and I don't know what options are available for managing multiple clients.  I'm assuming the easiest way is to simply have each ClientCreator instance die off once it's completed its work and have a central loop that can check to see if there's room to add a new client.  I would think this isn't a particularly unusual problem so I'm hoping to glean some information from other peoples' experiences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is really just to do the obvious thing here.  Don't have a loop, or a repeating timed call; just have handlers that do the right thing.

Keep a central connection-management object around, and make event-handling methods feed it the information it needs to keep going.  When it starts, make 5 outgoing connections.  Keep track of how many are in progress, maintain a list with them in it.  When a connection succeeds (in `connectionMade`) update the list to remember the connection's new state.  When a connection completes (in `connectionLost`) tell the connection manager; its response should be to remove that connection and make a new connection somewhere else.  In the middle, it should be fairly obvious how to fire off a request for the names you need and stuff them into a database (waiting for the database insert to complete before dropping your IRC connection, most likely, by waiting for the `Deferred` to come back from `adbapi`).

Answer (score 3):

Since each of your clients needs to update a database, instinctively I think I'd piggyback off the `connection pool` -- see [here](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/twisted_patterns.html#connection-pooling) for more (the whole doc is recommended for some important design patterns that often emerge when using twisted).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you are forced to use Twisted, otherwise you might want to give [Gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) a try.