# Twisted server for multiple clients

Tags: python, twisted

I want to write a server that can accept multiple clients in python (twisted). I am already quite familiar with socket programming with the standard python socket module but here comes the trouble..
I think twisted is really hard to get into and i have read some tutorials about it. 
But a thing that i can't really find is a simple socket server that accepts multiple connections.. Can anyone help? If i missed some valuable information online please let me know because i am pulling my hair out..

Any help is much appreciated,

Andesay

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365737/managing-multiple-twisted-client-connections

Comment: Andrew, I think that question is different from what Andesay asked. I feel that Andesay's question at much basic level. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Say, you want to run a server accepting client connections on port 9000:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

PORT = 9000

class MyServer(protocol.Protocol):
    pass

class MyServerFactory(protocol.Factory):
    protocol = MyServer

factory = MyServerFactory()
reactor.listenTCP(PORT, factory)
reactor.run()
```

And if you want to test connecting to this server, here's the code for a client (to launch in a different terminal):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9000

class MyClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connected!"

class MyClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = MyClient

factory = MyClientFactory()
reactor.connectTCP(HOST, PORT, factory)

reactor.run()
```

You'll notice the code is very similar, only we use a Factory for a server and a ClientFactory for a client, and the servers needs to listen (listenTCP) while the client needs to connect (connectTCP). Good luck!

Comment: I would say, the server code in one terminal and open multiple new terminals and try to connect using `nc localhost 9000` or `telnet localhost 9000`.  Using standard clients first helps.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome example.. I think this was just what i needed.. I have one question though.. In the server example under "class MyServer(protocol.Protocol)" you write a pass statement.. Why is nothing in this class?

Comment: And how would i go about sending and receiving data ?

Comment: a factory class needs a companion protocol class, so that's why it's defined. Since it's a barebones protocol it's empty but you can overload protocol methods there :-)

Comment: for sending data: use self.transport.write('your data here') in a protocol method. for receiving: implement dataReceived method (from protocol interface). Check out the tutorials given in other answers, they will help you.

Comment: Hey, do you guys know if I can use non-twisted client to connection to twisted server?

Answer (score 7):

I think, you did not get the essence of twisted. If you create a twisted socket server it is by default available connection via multiple clients. I would suggested the following tutorials in order and then read the twisted documentation. Write small snippets as its given in these tutorials to understand what is actually happening.

1. [Dave Peticola's twisted tutorial](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327)
2. [Itamar Shtull-Trauring's twisted presentation](http://itamarst.org/writings/OSCON03/twisted_internet-0.html)

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial is a great (best) starting point to learn how to write twisted server from scratch:
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Twisted is an awesome framework, but this (as often) implies that for easy thing it may be a quite hard...

Here's the fact. You need to write a class that implements a [Resource](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ClientFactory.html), a LineReceiver if you need, and then attach it to the reactor with:

```
reactor.connectTCP(<HOST>, <PORT>, istance_of_your_class)
```

Comment: Upon reflection, this answer doesn't make any sense at all.  You've linked 'resource' to 'ClientFactory', and I don't see how `connectTCP` is related to the asker's question at *all*; "accept multiple clients" sounds like the asker is writing a *server* not a client.  Resources are related only to HTTP, what does a `LineReceiver` have to do with anything, and what class are you talking about having an instance of?